# Is this mediation or a simple path?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, causality, mediation, amos, path-model

[image: model]

This is my model adapted from a study. I want to know whether I can only study it as a path analysis without studying mediation effect (1 $\longrightarrow$ 5 direct effect, as well as indirect effect) by just checking effect of one variable effect on another? I am using amos for this purpose.

All paths are significant except for the one between variables 3 and 5.
I have to submit it for a thesis and mediation seems to be quite difficult at this time.

Comment: Put box 1 on the left, and it will be clearer. Are there any correlations? Mediation isn't hard in AMOS (I think). If it wasn't done, I'd question why.

Comment: i dont know how to check correlation. can u please tell me how to? also how can i perform and report mediation? my supervisor just taught me to open results, check p value (***) and report standardized regression weights (2nd table under "estimates")

Comment: also plz tell if i dont report mediation in my analysis will it be considered a blunder? is it not possible just to check each variable effect with another and conclude that paths are significant mostly so our assumptions and model are proved?